# Sending nested data from Blade to Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have 3 models in a laravel application: 1) Lesson 2) Quiz 3) Answer (I should have named it Option actually). Their relationship is set up in this manner: Each Lesson has Quizzes, each Quiz has Answers. In a blade file I have access to a `$lesson` instance. I want to send both `$lesson->quizzes` and `$quiz->answers` from Blade to a VueJS method. Now I can only send the quizzes:

```
<modal-button color="success" size="small" icon="eye" header="View Quiz" btntxt="View Quiz" @showmodal="onShowViewQuizModal({{ $lesson->quizzes }})">
@include('partials.quizform')
</modal-button>
```

I capture the sent quizzes in my vuejs method and assign the array of objects to a vuejs data property:

```
onShowViewQuizModal(quizzes){
    this.quizzes = quizzes;
}
```

Within the `quizform` partial, I am trying to display these nested sets of data. I have something like this in my mind:

```
<div v-for="quiz in quizzes">
    <p>@{{ quiz.title }}</p>

    <div v-for="answer in quiz.answers">
        <p>@{{ answer.title }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the outer `v-for` will work, but the inner `v-for` won't because `quiz.answers` is probably `undefined`.

I hope you get the idea and I'm sure people must've come across this situation at some point. How can I handle the situation?

Comment: In Quiz model you need to make a relationship with Answer. In your Laravel Controller method do something like: Quiz::with('answers')->get();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a relationship in your Quiz model like this:

```
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Answer'); // second parameter can be used to define foreign key
}
```

In your Laravel Controller method do something like:

```
return Quiz::with('answers')->get();
```

Your VueJS will take care off the rest.

Comment: Correct answer here

Answer (score 0):

I'd aim to take care of that before the view is rendered... But this might do it.

```
<div v-for="quiz in quizzes">
    <p>@{{ quiz.title }}</p>
    <div v-if="quiz.answers">
      <div v-for="answer in quiz.answers">
          <p>@{{ answer.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To add a property to an object where is doesn't exist you could do something like this

```
for(x in quizzes){
  if(!x.hasOwnProperty('answers')){
    quizzes.x['answers] = []; <-- could use {} for object, depends what you're using for the answers when they exist
  }
}
```

and then...

```
<div v-for="quiz in quizzes">
    <p>@{{ quiz.title }}</p>
    <div v-if="quiz.answers && quiz.answers.length > 0">
      <div v-for="answer in quiz.answers">
          <p>@{{ answer.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's for arrays, now if `answers` is an object, you could use

```
Object.keys(quiz.answers).length === 0 && quiz.answers.constructor === Object
```

Comment: No it doesn't :( because `quiz` doesn't have any property called `answers`, I need a way to bind the answers to each quiz